# What does this two question mark mean?

Tags: swift

I met with this code, and I could not figure out what does this two question marks mean?

the Definition of this variable looks like following:

```
var featureImageSizeOptional: CGSize?
```

The code that makes me confused is:

```
let featureImageSize = featureImageSizeOptional ?? CGSizeZero
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's the *coalescing operator*.  It returns the first expression (`featureImageSizeOptional`) if it's non-nil. If the first expression is nil, the operator returns the second expression (`CGSizeZero`).

See [the Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-XID_123) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

The operator does not 'return the first expression' - it returns the unwrapped value of the first expression (if it is not nil).  From the Apple documentation (emphasis mine):

> The nil coalescing operator (a ?? b) ***unwraps*** an optional *a* if it
>   contains a value, or returns a default value *b* if a is *nil*. The
>   expression *a* is always of an optional type. The expression *b* must
>   match the type that is stored inside *a*.
>
> The nil coalescing operator is shorthand for the code below:
>
> a != nil ? ***a!*** : b
>
> The code above uses the ternary conditional operator and ***forced
>   unwrapping (a!) to access the value wrapped inside *a* when *a* is not
>   nil***, and to return *b* otherwise. The nil coalescing operator provides a
>   more elegant way to encapsulate this conditional checking and
>   unwrapping in a concise and readable form.